# How to display single SQLite data into textview?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to retrieve amount from an existing database and display it in a TextView.

I've created database. But when I'm trying to fetch and display the amount, my app keeps crash.

/*DataBaseHelper.java*/

```
   public Cursor getBalance(String amount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_BALANCE + " WHERE "
            + KEY_AMOUTNT + " = " + amount;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    Balance b = new Balance();
    b.setAmount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUTNT)));

    return (Cursor) b;
}
```

Dashboard class:

```
public void saveCallBack(Balance balance) {


   DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    Cursor cursor = dataBaseHelper.getBalance(DashBoard.email);
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String s_amount = "";
        s_amount = 
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEY_AMOUTNT));

        Double amount = 0.0;
        if (AppUtility.isNum(s_amount)) {
            amount = Double.parseDouble(s_amount);
        }

        TextView Amount = findViewById(R.id.amount);
        Amount.setText(String.valueOf(amount));


    }

}
```

Comment: If you're new to SQLite and Android, you might want to try the newer, easier and better [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). Here's the official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM) about it. Also, add logcat error file in your question whenever you have issues with Android.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a `Balance` to a `Cursor` which is not possible, and therefore your app will crash. You either want to return the database `Cursor` itself or the `Balance` object. You already made the `Balance` instance and placed some value in it, so I assume your code should be this:

```
public Balance getBalance(String amount) {
    ...

    Balance b = new Balance();
    b.setAmount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUTNT)));
    return b;
}
```

I would suggest you learn a bit more about casting in Java, so you will understand the casting behavior.

Comment: Thanks ,I changed this. But now I'm getting error in Dashboad.java 
  'Cursor cursor = dataBaseHelper.getBalance(DashBoard.email);

Comment: Yes, it's due the types. You should understand that `Cursor` is not and can never be a `Balance` object. You need to change your code structure, and really think of the types you are passing around. This will work: `Balance balance = dataBaseHelper.getBalance(DashBoard.email);`

Comment: I changed the structure but still getting error in DataBaseHelper.java.

Comment: As mentioned before, you should rethink of your structure and what you are passing around between classes. There is no real solution for other errors in your java class. If you have another question I would suggest you to post a new question on StackOverflow.